# My If statement isn't accepting '=='

Tags: c++, if-statement

I made a little game where the program jumbles up a word and asks for player input. However, one of the If statements are giving me an error and stopping me from compiling the program.

string isready;
cin >> isready;

if (isready == 'y' || 'Y')

Above I set up a string to be called isready, than asked the user for input. As seen above,
I wanted the if statement to activate if either y or capital y was typed in and received.
However, it just gives me the error:

invalid operands to binary expression ('string'
      (aka 'basic_string, allocator >') and 'int')

Perhaps I'm missing a #include file?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <ctime>
#include <unistd.h>
using namespace std;

int main()

{

enum fields {WORD, HINT, NUM_FIELDS};
const int NUM_WORDS = 5;
const string WORDS[NUM_WORDS][NUM_FIELDS] =    //5x2 array
{
    {"wall", "Do you feel you're banging your head against something?"},
    {"glasses", "These might help you see the answer."},
    {"labored", "Going slowly, is it"},
    {"persistent", "Keep at it."},
    {"jumble", "It's what the game is all about."}
};

srand(static_cast<unsigned int>(time(0)));
int choice = rand() % NUM_WORDS;
//Choice value in array, than area in array where word and hint are
string theWord = WORDS[choice][WORD]; //word to guess
string theHint = WORDS[choice][HINT]; //hint for word

string jumble = theWord;  //jumbled version of word
int length = jumble.size();
//Index1 and index2 are random locations in the string theWord
//last two lines swaps areas, ending the for function with a different
//jumble variable every time.
for (int i = 0; i < length; ++i)
{
    int index1 = rand() % length;
    int index2 = rand() % length;
    char temp = jumble[index1];
    jumble[index1] = jumble[index2];
    jumble[index2] = temp;
}

cout << "\t\tWelcome to Word Jumble!\n\n";
cout << "Unscramble the letters to make a word.\n";
cout << "\n\n\nReady? (y/n)";

//I'm asking here if the player is ready
string isready;
cin >> isready;

if (isready == 'y' || 'Y')
{
    cout << "Ok this is how the scoring works\n";
    cout << "The length of the word you will guess is times by 5000.\n";
    cout << "If you ask for a hint, your score will go down by half.\n";
    cout << "If you get the wrong answer, your score will go down by 1000.";
    cout << "\nOk, lets start!\n\n\n";
    int counter = 3;
    for(int i = 0; i < 3; ++i)
    {

        cout << counter << "..." << endl;
        counter--;
    }

    sleep(1);
}
else 
{
cout << "check";
}
cout << "Enter 'quit' to quit the game.\n";
cout << "Enter 'hint' for a hint.\n";
cout << "The jumble is: " << jumble;

//Score system
unsigned long int score;
int amount_of_guesses, amount_of_wrong = 0;




string guess;
cout << "\n\nYour guess: ";
cin >> guess;

while ((guess != theWord) && (guess != "quit"))
{
    if (guess == "hint")
    {
        cout << theHint;
        amount_of_guesses++;

    }

    else
    {
        cout << "Sorry, that's not it.";
        amount_of_wrong++;
    }

    cout << "\n\nYour guess: ";
    cin >> guess;
}
score = theWord.length() * 1000 -(amount_of_wrong * 1000)
/ 2 * amount_of_guesses;
if (guess == theWord)
{
    cout << "\nThat's it! You guessed it!\n";
}

cout << "Your score is: " << score;
cout << "\nThanks for playing.\n";
return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Operator `||` takes logical expressions on both sides:

```
if (isready == "y" || isready == "Y")
```

Note the double quotes above, because `isready` is a `std::string`. You could also change `isready` to `char`, and use character constants (i.e. `'y'` and `'Y'` in single quotes).

Your current expression is syntactically valid, but it will be evaluated as unconditional `true`, because it is interpreted as follows:

```
if (isready == 'y' || 'Y' != 0)
//                    ^^^^^^^^
//                    != 0 part is implicit;
//               `Y` != 0 is always true, so the entire OR is also always true
```

Comment: @lizusek Could you please be more specific as to what part will not compile?

Comment: comparison std::string to char

Answer (score 1):

here

```
(isready == 'y' || 'Y')
```

you are trying to use `operator==` on `std::string` and `char`, because 'y' is char. Apart from this conditions should be in parenthesis because `||` has lower precedence than `==`

Correct version is:

```
( (isready == "y") || ( isready == "Y"))  // use bool operator==
                                                       (const string& lhs, 
                                                            const string& rhs);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
(isready == 'y' || 'Y')
```

You should check for each character seperately.

```
((isready == "y" || (isready == "Y"))
```

Comment: this won't compile, @Mahesh please can you downvote your own answer

Comment: @lizusek Ahh .. Didn't notice that I amn't using double quotes. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
if (isready == 'y' || 'Y')
```

should be

```
if (isready == "y" || isready == "Y")
```

Answer (score 0):

Change this statement

```
if (isready == 'y' || 'Y')
```

to

```
if ( isready == "y" || isready == "Y")
```

Take into account that there are double quotes.

The problem is that there is no such operator == that can compare an object of type std::string with an object of type char. There is no such a constructor in class std::string that could convert implicitly an object of type char to an object of type std::string. However class std::string has a constructor that can convert a string literal to an object of type std:string. So the right operand that is "y" or "y" is implicitly converted to a temporary object of type std::string. As the result in the condition above two objects of type std::string are compared.

Also the condition you wrote initially is invalid even if you would use string literals instead of character literals. If for example `isready == "y"` was equal to `false` then you will get

```
false || "y"
```

In this expression string literal "y" is converted to a pointer to its first character. As this pointer is not equal to NULL then the whole expression will be `true` independing of the value in isready

Comment: This fixed my program, thank you. However, why did the double quotes do the trick, doesn't single letter characters require just single quotes?

Comment: @user3361175 In this expression isready == "y" the compiler searches an overlaoded operator == that can be applied. However there is no such operator that compares an object of type std::string with a character because the compiler can not convert implicitly  a char to type std::string. However the compiler can convert a string literal as for example "y" to an object of type std::string because there is an appropriate constructor in std::string that takes a string literal as an argument. So in fact you compare two objects of type std::string.